# Make DataGridView stretch to middle of WinForms form?

Tags: c#, winforms, layout

I have a WinForm form that has two DataGridView controls paced on it such that they are stacked, one above the other against the right hand side of the form.

I would like a way of setting them so that when I expand the form, they expand height-wise with it, as well as width-wise. I managed width-wise by anchoring them to the left and right sides and anchoring the top one to the top and the bottom one to the bottom. However, from here I'm not sure how to get them to use up the space in the middle that appears when the form maximizes...Maybe an image will make my meaning clearer:

Normal Size:
[image: Normal size form]

Maxmized; I'd like the grids to expand to take up the full height of the form *between the two of them* as the red arrows show:
[image: Maximized form with annotation]

If this question is blindingly obvious I apologise and can only say I didn't really know how to phrase it properly and so found searching for it on Google unhelpful!

Comment: Use an achored TableLayoutPanel to host the two grids.  Set their row heights to 50%.

Comment: Or use an anchored (top|bottom|left|right) SplitPanel. You can even give the users the choice to changer the split, if you want to.

Comment: @TaW Ooh, that sounds good... though I had been hoping for some setting that would avoid me having to dicker about actually moving the controls again

Comment: Just drop them into the two panes, set them dock=fill and decide on fixing the splitter or not. __Correction__: The name of the control is `SplitContainer`. Make sure no pane is `fixed` !

Comment: @TaW Hoo-ee, that really fits the bill! If you'd like to make that an answer I'll accept :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

- `TableLayoutPanel` or
- `SplitContainer`

The former lets you create a table of many columns and/or rows with various sizing options from `absolute` and `percent` to `autosize`. This is very powerful for layout; but in other respects `TLPs` are somewhat restricted as the *'cells'* are only **virtual**..

A `SplitContainer` offers only **two** panes but lets you treat each with all the things you can do to a `container`: add one or more controls, anchor or dock them, give each pane a BackColor and make use of its event model.

So if you need just two controls of equal size that adapt to the form size like you showed in the question, a `SplitContainer` is maybe the better option.

Set the splitter to fixed and make it smaller, **anchor** the `SplitContainer` to **all sides** and drop the `DGVs` into their panes and `Dock` them to `Fill`.

You could also make the splitter moveable to allow the user to resize the panes; if you do that do make the splitter width larger..

Also make sure that the `FixedPanel` is set to `None` so that height changes are shared.

**Hint**: If you want a few more panes to share the space you can **nest** several `SplitContainers`.. But for larger numbers do consider switching to `TLP`!